# Issue in preserving alternate table row background color with jQuery animate()

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table with alternate row background color.

```
<table class="tb_record">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS for this table and its alternate row background color is:

```
.tb_record {
    width:50%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.tb_record th, .tb_record td {
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
}

.tb_record tr.odd  {
    background-color:#FAFBFB;
}

.tb_record tr.even  {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

To change the table row background color, I am using jQuery animate() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".tb_record tr", function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"background-color": "#F5F5F5"}, "fast")
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".tb_record tr", function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"background-color": "#FFFFFF"}, "fast")
    });
});
```

But this jQuery code is creating an annoying issue. It changes background color of each row to white when the mouse is taken outside of the table row. How can we retain table row's original background color when mouse leaves the row?

I know above goal can easily be achieve with the help of CSS but I want to use animate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following jQuery snippet of code will do the task:

```
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".tb_record tr:not(:first-child)", function(){
        $(this).data("bg-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"background-color": "#F5F5F5"}, "fast")
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".tb_record tr", function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"background-color": $(this).data('bg-color')}, "fast")
    });
```

Here, I am storing the background color of each row except the very first row (header) while mouse hovers over them in the data attribute. And this value is further used when the mouse leaves the table rows to restore original table row color.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you need a method of storing the original colour instead of setting every row back to white on mouseout. You could do that by storing `data` attributes on the element when the page loads, or reading if the index of the current row is odd/even when the mouseout occurs.

***However*** this can be done much more simply by using CSS.

You just need two rules. One to set the `transition` to achieve the animation you want, and another to set the colour on `:focus`.

```css
.tb_record tr {
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.tb_record tr:hover {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

This also removes the need for the jQuery library I assume you're using to animate the background colour, as that is not standard functionality.

```css
.tb_record {
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.tb_record th,
.tb_record td {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.tb_record tr {
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.tb_record tr.odd {
  background-color: #FAFBFB;
}

.tb_record tr.even {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tb_record tr:hover {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tb_record">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But I want to use jQuery animate() method as I already told that I could achieve it easily by using CSS.

Comment: Then you should really do it using CSS. JS is very far from an ideal solution for this. If you really want to do this in JS, I assume as a learning exercise, then you can use the approach I outlined in the first paragraph